# How to optionally call mutator in lumen

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

i use mutator in my model to encrypt id:

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return encrypt($value);
}
```

but I want the default value to be the original value of the id and call the mutator when needed. is that possible?

Comment: as far  as i know, you can't call accessor conditionally but you can get the original value using `$user->getRawOriginal('id')`

Comment: @zahidhasanemon thanks for answering, I've tried it but it seems it only works for single data. how to use it on all data collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to call the original value, and sometimes the encrypted value why don't you just add an extra function to your model ?
You won't use a mutator since you want to be able to grab the original value, but you can add an extra function like this in your model which you will be able to call when you want to receive encrypted value.

```
public function encryptedId()
    {
        return encrypt($this->id);
    }
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: seems to only work for single collection data, but this gave me the idea to make a mutator for custom column like getEncryptedIdAttribute(). And then call with select('id as encrypted_id'), thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can using getRawOriginal() to get original value in lumen:

for example:

```
$model = Model::find('model_id');
return $model->getRawOriginal('column_name'));
```